# Did Kartikeya have any children?

Tags: kartikeya

I know that Kartikeya (Murugan) was married to Devasena and Valli. Did he have any children with them or otherwise?

Comment: The Vana Parva of Mahabharata says Kartikeya had numerous children from his injury.